# Uri uri = new Uri ("psCom;component/Resources/Images.xaml", UriKind.Relative); uses an old version of the Images.xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resources

everybody,

have already found a lot of information here, now it is time for the first own question:

I have created a dll in Visual Studio 2019, which e.g. provides images as a resource. I want to access it in a WPF app. This works quite well with XAML and all imags ar visible:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/psCom;component/Resources/Images.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</Window.Resources>
```

But now I want to start the app from another application so that I can give an object as parameter.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private object Test
    public App(object Test)
    {
        this.Test = Test;
        this.Run();
    }
}
```

If I do that, suddenly the last added images are no longer in the dictionary. It looks like the Images.xaml that is called here is about two months old.

When I create the Uri in the code behind,

```
Uri uri = new Uri("myDll;component/Resources/Images.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary { Source = uri });
```

I can also see that MergedDictionares[0].Keys does not contain the newer images.

Is it possible that Visual Studio uses a wrong version of the dll here (e.g. from a backup or test installation)? I have cleaned and rebuilt the WPF project several times.

Thanks a lot
Markus

Comment: A relative resource file URI looks odd. Why aren't you using a full URI in code behind? Like `Uri uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/myDll;component/Resources/Images.xaml");`

Comment: Okay, there was something missing, I added. No change, though. In the editor I can see the graphics, at runtime (debug and release) they are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Now I have found the error myself. Due to a change in the directory structure, the path to the dll in the references was no longer correct.

But I don't know why it worked in XAML. I also find it very surprising that Visual Studio doesn't report an error here, but seems to randomly use a different version of the dll.

I also found out that it is better to have the two projects in one solution. The access is then easier and safer.